# Unable to start service lateinit property has not been initialized

Tags: android, kotlin

Hi and thank you for your expertise.

I am trying to run a service which is going to display a notification and after some time check if it is still there or user has got rid of it.

So in the MainActivity.kt when onPause function is triggered I start the service like this

```
startService(Intent(this,NewService::class.java))
```

then in the NewService.kt I would like to check using MainActivity.kt function checkNotifications() if there is a notification displayed

```
class NewService:Service() {
    
    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    override fun onStartCommand(init : Intent, flag : Int, startId: Int):Int{
        MainActivity().checkNotifications()
        return  START_STICKY
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
    }

    override fun onBind(p0: Intent?): IBinder? {
        return null
    }

}
```

This is what checkNotifications() function in MainActivity.kt looks like

```
    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    fun checkNotifications(){
        val notifications: Array<StatusBarNotification> = notificationManager.activeNotifications

        if(notifications.isNotEmpty())
        {
            println("Notification exists")
        }
        else
        {
            println("No notifications")
        }
    }
```

So my app works 'fine' as long as I don't call checkNotifications(). What I mean the service starts and so on. However when I try to call checkNotifications() I get this error

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service abc.com.app.NewService@b380e9f with Intent { cmp=abc.com.app/.NewService }: kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property notificationManager has not been initialized

The property notificationManager is initialized in onCreate() function and everyting is working up until I call checkNotifications()

Would anyone be so kind and tell me what am I doing wrong?

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

```kotlin
MainActivity().checkNotifications()
```

**Never** create an instance of an activity yourself. Move `checkNotifications()` into the service or into some utility class (where you provide a `Context` as a parameter to `checkNotifications()` for the purposes of obtaining a `NotificationManager`).